# SVG canvas size limitations

Tags: javascript, html, svg

#### Problem

I was planning on using SVG as an infinite canvas on which I can move around using `viewBox`.
Turns out that when the viewbox reaches a specific sweetspot, the shapes start disappearing.

#### Example

Watch how the shapes always stay inside of the view box, until the viewbox passes the sweetspot:
[image: Shapes escaping viewbox example]

[Live reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7uffsx)

It's as if SVG has a limitation mismatch where the viewbox can keep running freely, but shapes can only render within specific bounds.

#### Research

Furthermore, the sweetspot is different between browsers:

- On Chrome it's `33554399`.
- On Firefox it's `17895590`.

The same happens on the other direction. Apply a minus sign to the above values and the shapes disappear on the other side of the canvas.

My best guess is that the browser implementation of SVG is internally constrained by something parallel to `Number.MAX_VALUE` (but is significantly lower).
However, I couldn't find any relevant documentation on the subject.

#### Question

Any way to fix or work around this? I'm hoping to keep my current implementation and not simulate the viewbox on my own.

Comment: To workaround: use smaller numbers.

Comment: I guess one way to work around it would be splitting the svg into smaller ones, and having them perfectly side-by-side? I have a hard time picturing a scenario where you'd actually need that much space, but by building square svg's of 17895590px per side, and having "utils" functions to easily transition from one to the next, it could be done.

Comment: @RobertLongson Do you mean drawing my shapes inside the "permitted" bounds? It would mean I would have to rewrite parts of the code to calculate shape positions to kind of simulate an infinite canvas on a small one. I'm trying to avoid that...

Comment: @JulienRipet Interesting idea. I have to analyze how it affects my code. Gives me the impression though that coordinating "tiles" would create more complexity than simulating infinite rendering. 

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a floating point precision problem.

The Chrome value is very close to 2**25, 33554432, where floating point values go from having a distance of two between them to having a distance of 4, and adding one does nothing (below this point, n+1 might round up to n+2; but after this point n+1 will definately round back down to n.

This might explain the shaking that's seen before the image scrolls off to the side; different mathematical operations

https://float.exposed/0x4bfffff0

The Firefox number is less obvious: it's firmly in the regime where the distance between values is two (it's about 1.125 * 2**24), so it's less clear why it fails at this point, but the root cause is likely to be similar -- basic mathematics on the integers is breaking down.

If you're really, truly committed to making these work on Chrome or Firefox, you might be able to recompile using 64-bit floats (which would not have these mathematical errors until numbers well in excess of 9 quadrillion, but this is a surprisingly significant endeavour.

Also, thank you. Your video demonstrated clearly the problems I was encountering whilst abusing SVG to attempt to make a 1:1 scale model of the solar system, inspired by today's [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2761/), and helps me understand why it wasn't working the way I wanted it to.

Hope you've found a better solution in the intervening two years!

Comment: On the topic of floating point number error abuse, I'd recommend pannenkoek2012's video on "How to crash Super Mario 64 using a pendulum" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYDmBdUalgo if you've got an hour to waste... :)

(you can use the chapters to skip to the more relevant bits)